# Ionic serve command - Browser doesn't load the project (blank page)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, git-bash

```
//gulpfile error and how it was fixed :
```

Whenever I try to run my Ionic project on the localhost using `ionic serve` command I get an error as shown in the picture below

I am using git Bash

**PS. when I created the project in the first time I saved it in the Desktop, now the project is saved in another folder in the desktop**

[image: Screenshot - Git Bash preview]

**UPDATE**

The problem was fixed by using removing `node_modules` file and running `npm install` command and then renaming the `ionic.project` to `ionic.config.json` the problem I am facing now is that when I run `ionic serve` command the browser doesn't load the project and I'm left with a blank web page with nothing on it

Comment: Try removing `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.

Comment: where exactly should I run `npm install` ?

Comment: In your current project directory. `cd Desktop/new_folder/your_app`

Comment: it sort of worked but now iss showing me "WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it." and the browser opens and nothing is shown just a blank page

Comment: what version of npm are you running?

Comment: Could you please update the question and post the console logs, the exact issue you're facing along with the version of npm and ionic?

Comment: Question update, please take time to review the updated part, Thanks everyone